# How to work with Boolean values in MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a `Boolean entry` through the `mongoose schema`. The parameters are : `username,password and admin`.

The admin parameter is set as boolean and default value as "true".
Now while making an entry through post request, if I skip making the admin field, then its value gets stored as `true`.

But if I explicitly mention it as `false`, then the `value is not stored in the database`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post your code, that will be more clear to give your answer?

Comment: var User = new Schema({
 username:String,
 password:String,
 admin: {
  type:Boolean,
  default:false
 }
});

This is the schema that is being used

Comment: How are you storing the value can you post here

Comment: I am doing this as a part of an API. I am using Advanced REST client for running the api. The JSON data that I am sending is being sent as a part of the http request body as:
{"name":"abcd","password":"abcd","admin":false}

Now for such case, if I have set admin default as true, then the value stored is true, irrespective of the value mentioned here

Comment: If you do not provide how your saving code is written, nobody can help you

Comment: Oh am sorry.

    router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
        User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }),
          req.body.password,req.body.admin, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({err: err});
            }
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration     Successful!'});
            });
        });
    });

This is the part through which registration takes place.

Comment: Where is your `User.register` method? and why you put other property outside in your object?

Answer (score 0):

A javascript boolean can only either be true, or false.  If it isn't true then it must be false.  So any boolean field stored in the database without a value must be false (since it isn't true).

Comment: On removing the "default" parameter from the schema, the vale is getting stored as false only, even on mentioning it as "true", while making an entry.
Any idea on such behaviour?